# java bean to wsdl - how to make fields nillable?

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl, jax-ws

I'm using JAX-WS api for wsdl generation. 
Java-bean class is something like:

```
public class MyBean {
    private String nullableField;
    private String notNullableField;

    // and here appropriate get/set/ters
}
```

When wsdl is generated then nullability of this fields is not specified.

Question: what (and where) necessary to specify that fields have corresponding nillable='' value in wsdl? I.e. how can I specify fields nullability in plain java code for wsdl?

At this time I'm generating wsdl and then correcting xml manually for fields nullability. That's not convenient. I want this `nillable` attribute'll be generated by java-ws automatically.

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using an IDE(Netbeans or Eclipse) to create the wsdl from the bean?

Comment: @ChadNC The OP is using JAX-WS

Comment: btw, nillable != nullable. If you want a field to be nullable you set its minOccurs to 0. Not sure if you can set that with a WebParam.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, it is still not possible to generate `nillable=false` when using `@WebParam` i.e. when using  a Java-first approach (as discussed in [this thread](http://forums.java.net/jive/thread.jspa?messageID=313569)). Actually, I'd recommend to use a WSDL-first approach if you want fine control.

Comment: Ok. I've hot yet used wsdl-first approach. But I'll try. Thank you!